# oracle 11g get regex submatches

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g

for my pl/sql procedure i have to extract the submatches from a text field and insert those values into another table...

The Regex is something like: `/^(xyz|abc)(\w{3,3})(\d{0,2})(\d{2,2})(a|ab|ef)$/`

so what i want is basically something like this in pseudo-sql:

```
select 
  rtbl.1,  -- should return xyz
  rtbl.2,  -- should return GGG
  rtbl.3,  -- should return 1
  rtbl.4,  -- should return xyz
  rtbl.5   -- should return ef
from regex('xyzGGG122ef', /^(xyz|abc)(\w{3,3})(\d{0,2})(\d{2,2})(a|ab|ef)$/) rtbl;
```

how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_substr` to get submatches:

```
SELECT 
  regexp_substr('xyzGGG122ef', '^(xyz|abc)(\w{3,3})(\d{0,2})(\d{2,2})(a|ab|ef)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1),
  regexp_substr('xyzGGG122ef', '^(xyz|abc)(\w{3,3})(\d{0,2})(\d{2,2})(a|ab|ef)$', 1, 1, NULL, 2),
  regexp_substr('xyzGGG122ef', '^(xyz|abc)(\w{3,3})(\d{0,2})(\d{2,2})(a|ab|ef)$', 1, 1, NULL, 3),
  regexp_substr('xyzGGG122ef', '^(xyz|abc)(\w{3,3})(\d{0,2})(\d{2,2})(a|ab|ef)$', 1, 1, NULL, 4),
  regexp_substr('xyzGGG122ef', '^(xyz|abc)(\w{3,3})(\d{0,2})(\d{2,2})(a|ab|ef)$', 1, 1, NULL, 5)
FROM dual;
```

The group that you want to get is the last parameter.
Read more here: [Oracle Documentation on regexp_substr](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/functions159.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification to above answer:

```
SELECT
      ROWNUM,
      POS
FROM
      (SELECT
            REGEXP_SUBSTR (
                         'xyzGGG122ef',
                         '^(xyz|abc)(\w{3,3})(\d{0,2})(\d{2,2})(a|ab|ef)$',
                         1,
                         1,
                         NULL,
                         ROWNUM )
                POS
       FROM
            DUAL
       CONNECT BY
            LEVEL <= 5) RTBL;
```